# Facebook profile picture not downloading

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I just started facebook integration, and in my app am downloading details of the user.
Now the thing is I am getting all other details except the profile pic which when NSloged returns null.
What am I doing wrong. I have given permissions for basic info.
Please help me. Thanx in advance.

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];

```
// Send request to Facebook
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

        nickname.text= userData[@"name"];
        firstName.text=userData [@"first_name"];
        lastName.text=userData[@"last_name"];
        city.text=userData[@"user_location"];
        gender.text= userData[@"gender"];
        dateOfBirth.text = userData[@"birthday"];


        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", userData[@"id"]]];

        NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pictureURL];
        NSLog(@" profile pic data = %@", data);
        self.imageToUpload.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        NSString *imgstr=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",imgstr);

        [PFUser logOut];

        // Now add the data to the UI elements
        // ...
    }
}];
```

Comment: You got other informations?

Comment: yea , I received the name, firstname, lastname, user_location, gender, birthday

Comment: So, you didn't get your 'id' from facebook?.

Comment: I got id, and if I check that url in browser i can see the image. but its not loading in the app. That imgstr is returning null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the id of logged in user by requesting this url

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me
```

and then you can request for the profile pic by creating url like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<userid>/picture
```

I hope this helps.

You may get exact idea here

```
   -(void)getFacebookAccounts {

        ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"appid",  ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                                 [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"], ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                                 nil];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options
                                           completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

                                               if (granted && !error) {
                                                   accountsList = (NSMutableArray*)[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

                                                   int NoOfAccounts = [accountsList count];

                                                   if (NoOfAccounts > 1) {

                                                       NSLog(@"device has more then one twitter accounts %i",NoOfAccounts);

                                                   }
                                                   else
                                                   {
                                                       NSLog(@"device has single twitter account : 0");

                                                       if([accountsList count] > 0)
                                                       {
                                                           myAccount = [accountsList objectAtIndex:0];
                                                           [self getProfilePic];
                                                       }
                                                       else
                                                       {
                                                           UIAlertView *altviw=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Set an account in the settings of the device" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                                                           [altviw show];
                                                           altviw=nil;
                                                       }


                                                   }
                                               }
                                               else
                                               {
                                                   // show alert with information that the user has not granted your app access, etc.
                                               }

                                           } ];
    }
    -(void) getProfilePic{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"];
    NSDictionary *p = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myAccount.username, @"screen_name", nil];

    SLRequest *FBrequest= [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                            URL:url
                                                     parameters:p];

    [FBrequest setAccount:myAccount];
    [FBrequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error) {

         }
         NSError *jsonError = nil;
         // Convert the response into a dictionary
         NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];

  NSString *strId1= [dictResponse objectForKey:@"id"];
   NSString *strurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", strId1];
   if(!arrmPics)
             {
                 arrmPics=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             }
           dispatch_async

             (dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                 NSData *imageData =

                 [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:

                  [NSURL URLWithString: strurl]];

                 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [arrmPics addObject:imageData];
                     imgviw.image=image;
                 });
             } );
} ];

     }
```

Comment: Check my code posted in edit. Because I can see image in response at my end.

Comment: Yea ofcourse, it was jus my mistake. I just found it from your code. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can never download user image facebook dont allow it i send weeks on it a while ago but didn't work in any way.

but from my experience you don't need image @ all just url will work every place you need if you need help on how to display image i can help you

http://m-farhan.com/2014/03/ios-facebook-sdk-tutorial/

check step (6)

and download project there is library SDWebImage folder drag in your project

```
#import "SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h"


    [userImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large",[user objectForKey:@"id"]]]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknownUser.png"]]

;
```

Comment: ohke, so how do we do it, I have used the image url with facebook id, it returns the image in browser. What am i doing wrong here

Comment: so now you know how to store image in html for ios i ll update answer in 2 min its 3 like code and it will work fine

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But Poojas asynchronous method helped.